# Category page image upload issue

Tags: category, image-upload

I am trying to upload Thumbnail image and image for category page but it is neither uploading nor showing any error.
I have cleared cache and also done indexing but still no output

Any solution??

Comment: check your exception log file. when there is any error in image upload for category magento is not throwing any error instead it log exception

Comment: where is exception log file located?

Comment: at dir var/log/ and make sure log is on from admin panel

Comment: from admin panel means ?? from where?

Comment: admin->System->Configuration->Developer->Log Settings->Enabled->Yes 
select default confing from Configuration Scope on left

Comment: exception log file is not there. i have enabled log from admin panel

Answer (score 0):

1. Verify the existence of `media/catalog/category` directory with correct permissions
2. Check your `media/catalog/category` folder is named with `.jpg` or `.png`. If yes, then delete these folder.
3. Flush your Magento chache.

Comment: all steps already followed.

Comment: Did you try it in other browser ?

Comment: yes i tried in other browsers also